# Transform array to strings in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert this array

```
array(3) {
  ["Men"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Sport shoes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Football shoes"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["Winter shoes"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["Women"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Childrens"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

to this result

```
Men
Men -> Sport shoes 
Men -> Sport Shoes -> Football shoes 
Men -> Winter shoes 
Women 
Childrens
```

I tried a lot of methods but without success.
Can someone tell me how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible recursive approach could work like this:

Starting with an empty string, iterate the array and append each key to the result. Before continuing to the next iteration, if the value is not empty, append the result of the recursive call. When you get to the end, you should have a string representing the entire structure.

```
function get_map(array $array, string $path = ''): string
{
    $result = '';
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $result .= "$path$key\n" . ($value ? get_map($value, "$path$key->") : '');
    }
    return $result;
}
echo get_map($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with simple recursive function like this:

```
function printArray($array, $path = []) {
    if (!is_array($array) || count($array) < 1) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (count($path) > 0) {
            echo implode(' -> ', $path) . ' -> ';
        }
        echo $k . PHP_EOL;
        printArray($v, array_merge($path, [$k]));
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://glot.io/snippets/f4wbfo0ia4)

Comment: Yes, it works but how to return the value as a string?